# org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication import throwing error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/creating-spring-boot-project-using-sts) using Spring Tool Suites.

I've copied what it says and my code and pom look the same (copied for easy review)

```
package com.javatpoint.spring_boot_example_sts;  
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;    
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;   

@SpringBootApplication    
public class SpringBootExampleSts   
{  
   public static void main(String[] args){    
      SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleSts.class, args);    
   }   
}
```

My issue is that I am getting a red line under ' org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication. To my knowledge, this library is not deprecated and I can't seem to find any instance of it being moved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error

Comment: probably the dependencies don't download properly

Comment: Fetch/update the dependencies from remote repository by running maven update.

Answer (score 0):

May be maven either maven dependency is not downloaded or your IDE has some issues.
You can try to restart your IDE.
If issue still persist, Please build using mvn clean package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).